# Generate Transparent Text Image OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How can I create an image which is transparent except the pixels of a given text in python `opencv`?

I have found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957661/5330223) in `C++` which creates an image without transparency. So when merging them together, the solution just adds the pixels. Which makes the text pixel intensity variable depending on the background image.

```
Mat img = imread("lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

// Create and rotate the text
Mat textImg = Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());
putText(textImg, "stackoverflow", Point(0, img.cols/2), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.0,Scalar(20,20,20),2);

// Sum the images (add the text to the original img)
img= img+textImg;

namedWindow("WaterMark", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("WaterMark", img);
```

So, one way would be to make a mask image from the text and then use it to generate the alpha channel. But is there a better solution for this.

Comment: Do you want to make an existing image transparent or create a new one?

Comment: I want to create a new one only with the text pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
image = np.zeros((100,300,4),np.uint8)
cv2.putText(image, "Test String", (10,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,3,(0,0,255,255))
```

[image: result]